# Get sdcard directory by adb

Tags: android, adb, sd-card

I am making an application, which pulls files(Saved by android app) from the device sdcard by adb. 
The problem is that different devices, have various sdcard directories

i.e:

- sdcard
- sdcard/external_sd

Firstly I invented following solution:

1. run adb shell
2. ls
3. Check if dir "sdcard" exists
4. If yes run sdcard/ ls and check if external_sd exists
5. return value.

But the problem is that I have two samsung devices `GT-I9100` and `GT-I9000` and both have a directory `sdcard/external_sd`. When I am checking `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` one returns `sdcard` and another `sdcard/external_sd`. I need to pull file which was previously saved to `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")`.

> So the question is: is there any command to get sdcard directory
>   directly from adb, without access to Android code?
>
> Or maybe I can start activity with adb's am start, and get return
>   value? Is this possible?

EDIT:
Found the solution:

```
adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: you might want to escape the $

Comment: When I am using `adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it escape the $ automatically.

When I am doing it in this way:
 1. `adb shell`
 2. `echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
I have to end it with `exit` to escape the $

Comment: Duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14105/32571

Answer (score 29):

For what its worth - using the $EXTERNAL_STORAGE variable can give you misleading results.
I have a HP Slate tablet here, which has the EXTERNAL_STORAGE variable set to /storage/sdcard0 . 
However when using df (disk free) command on shell, or even the mount command to display free space or mounts, the following becomes obvious:

```
shell@android:/ $ df
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                  452.7M  36.0K  452.7M   4096
/mnt/asec             452.7M  0.0 K  452.7M   4096
/mnt/obb              452.7M  0.0 K  452.7M   4096
/system               629.9M  468.5M  161.5M   4096
/data                 5.7 G  2.3 G  3.5 G   4096
/cache                435.9M  16.4M  419.5M   4096
/storage/sdcard0      5.7 G  2.3 G  3.5 G   4096
/mnt/external_sd      29.3G  64.0K  29.3G   32768
```

so, the external sd card is in fact /mnt/external_sd, instead of the value EXTERNAL_STORAGE returns(which is the internal storage)

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you John !

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

If I've not misunderstood you, you're looking for something like:

```
emanuele@Nabucodonosor:~$ adb shell cd \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
emanuele@Nabucodonosor:~$ adb shell ls \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
emanuele@Nabucodonosor:~$ adb shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Found the solution "adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE" basing on your comment, thank you.

Comment: This is not the right answer. The answer of John Deaux is good.

Comment: On my device $EXTERNAL_STORAGE is actually the internal memory for some stupid reason. John Deaux is right, `df` is the way to go!

Comment: The answer is very old

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) instead of `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` This will give you external storage directory irrespective of device.

Comment: irrespective of device ? 
You mean that System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")  can not work on some devices?

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() means external application storage, not external device storage.

Google seems to have had a design era where expandable device memory was removed from Android. They are putting it back, but the results are are mess. Post Lollipop, mounting external storage (sdcards, usb, net drives, etc) should be straight forward.

Comment: I wanted to access sdcard from shell script, this answer helped me a lot. I don't understand why people are voting it down...